# How to read EAN-13 bar Code from Android device (Not QR Code)

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am working with an Android Application and I am successful in reading the `QR Code` from android mobile, but still I am curious to find the way to scan **EAN-13 Bar code** from Android Mobile.

If anyone has idea on this, please suggest me?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156402/Android-Generating-an-EAN13-Barcode) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) scanner can do that. You can either use the library or the installed application from your app.

Comment: I know that , but dear henry , ZXing is not working for BAR Code. Even its is working for QR- COde .....Thanks for your response